# La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto. C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql

tengo un  error, como menciono en el  título bueno resulta que ando  haciendo un webform en  c# y al ejecutarlo me da  ese error
Aquí mi código:

```
public void Ordenes(int ID_Orden)
{
    conectar();
    consulta = "P_SANCHEZ_ORDEN";
    comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion);
    comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_ORDEN",ID_Orden);
    comando.Parameters.Add("@FECHAORDEN", SqlDbType.NVarChar,10).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    comando.Parameters.Add("@SUB", SqlDbType.Money).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    comando.Parameters.Add("@IVA", SqlDbType.Money).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    comando.Parameters.Add("@TOTAL", SqlDbType.Money).Direction= ParameterDirection.Output;
    comando.Connection.Open(); // Abre la conexion
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Ejecuta 
    FechaOrden = comando.Parameters["@FECHAORDEN"].Value.ToString();
     sub = float.Parse(comando.Parameters["@SUB"].Value.ToString()); <--- En esta línea me marca ese error
    IVA = float.Parse(comando.Parameters["@IVA"].Value.ToString());
    Total = float.Parse(comando.Parameters["@TOTAL"].Value.ToString());
    comando.Connection.Close(); //Cierra
}
```

Luego,  según mi profesor me dice que es el SQL en mi procedimiento... Pero éste no me marca ningún error y al revisarlo tooodo funciona a la perfección.

```
CREATE PROC P_SANCHEZ_ORDEN -- DROP PROC P_SANCHEZ_ORDEN
@ID_ORDEN INT,
@FECHAORDEN NVARCHAR (10) OUTPUT,
@SUB MONEY OUTPUT,
@IVA MONEY OUTPUT,
@TOTAL MONEY OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
select convert(nvarchar(10),FechaOrden,103) from Ordenes where ID_Orden = @ID_ORDEN
SELECT SUM(TOTALART) FROM V_SANCHEZ_DETALLEORDEN WHERE ID_Orden = @ID_ORDEN
SELECT SUM(TOTALART) *.16 FROM V_SANCHEZ_DETALLEORDEN WHERE ID_Orden = @ID_ORDEN
SELECT SUM(TOTALART)*1.16 FROM V_SANCHEZ_DETALLEORDEN WHERE ID_Orden = @ID_ORDEN
END
```

Me podrán ayudar a identificar por qué se produce ese error por favor?

Comment: Es preferible que no publiques tu email en el sitio. Puedes arriesgarte a que te llenen de spam.

Comment: Oh sh*t Gracias ^^ por la info la tendré en cuenta :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien dice tu profesor, el problema esta en el procedimiento almacenado. Estás declarando unos parámetros de salida, pero nunca les estás asignando valor. Debes modificar los `SELECT` para que asignen el resultado a tus parámetros:

```
select @FECHAORDEN = convert(nvarchar(10),FechaOrden,103) from Ordenes where ID_Orden = @ID_ORDEN
SELECT @SUB= SUM(TOTALART) FROM V_SANCHEZ_DETALLEORDEN WHERE ID_Orden = @ID_ORDEN
SELECT @IVA = SUM(TOTALART) *.16 FROM V_SANCHEZ_DETALLEORDEN WHERE ID_Orden = @ID_ORDEN
SELECT @TOTAL = SUM(TOTALART)*1.16 FROM V_SANCHEZ_DETALLEORDEN WHERE ID_Orden = @ID_ORDEN
```

Comment: LOL tenía la idea de que iba por ahí.... Muuchas gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Alonso,

El problema que tienes es que estás intentando castear el tipo `Money` de SQL con un `Float`, con el cual no es posible esa conversión.

Deberías usar el tipo `Decimal` para castear el `Money`:

```
decimal sub;
decimal IVA;
decimal Total;

sub = Convert.ToDecimal(comando.Parameters["@SUB"].Value.ToString());
IVA = Convert.ToDecimal(comando.Parameters["@IVA"].Value.ToString());
Total = Convert.ToDecimal(comando.Parameters["@TOTAL"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Lo acabo  de intentar y me marca el mismo error hay alguna forma de poner float en SQL o algo similar?